# Get Current Custom Sharepoint List Item Row Number for XSLT

Tags: 2013, custom-list, xslt

```
...    
    <xsl:apply-templates select='Rows/Row'/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match='Row'>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </xsl:template>
...
```

I have a custom sharepoint list.And I try to make a slider with using the list column values.

I need to get the current item row number.    **data-slide-to** has that row number. And the result will be like below. How can I do it ?

```
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
```

**New Code**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">

    <xsl:output method='html' indent='yes'/>

    <xsl:template match='dsQueryResponse' xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide  bt-nav-mar" data-ride="carousel"> 

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <xsl:apply-templates select='Rows/Li'/>
        </ol>   
        <div class="carousel-inner">          
            <xsl:apply-templates select='Rows/Row'/>

        </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
            </a> 
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
            </a>    

    </div> 


    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match='Li'>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" >
            <xsl:attribute name="data-slide-to">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>     

    <xsl:template match='Row'>

         <div class="item"> 
         <a href="/../Lists/Duyurular/DispForm.aspx?ID={string(@ID)}"  class="fontText">

            <img alt="gallery thumbnail" ><xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Picture"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute></img>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3><xsl:value-of select="@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></h3>
              <p><xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></p>
            </div>
          </a>
         </div>


     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the number parameter

```
<xsl:number/>
```

or you could try `position()`

```
<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
```

Comment: I tried it but I guess my "xsl:template match" is wrong. So I don't know that it works or not. Can you check my new code in question? I can't write Rows/Row twice, so i wrote Rows/Li but It is wrong i guess :/

Comment: what output do you get?

Comment: <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>

Comment: Yeah you can not iterat the li:s you must get i to work on every Row

Comment: I use position() for a condition im Rows/Row that I ve just wrote. Thank you so much! And I will ask the using Rows/Row again in a new question. Because I couldn't find how to do it.